# Can I configure ReturnUrl on logout in sustainsys-saml2?

Tags: sustainsys-saml2

I have set up `SLO` with `sustainsys-saml2` for a MVC-project and it seems to work but the problem is that we get returned to the entrypoint after logout. In my `dev-environment` I am using the `stubidp` from `sustainsys` and I will get the startscreen for `stubidp` directly after logout and that is ok but in a testenvironment with `ADFS` as `idp` it will automatically log in again.

I have tested to logout by adding `/AuthServices/Logout?ReturnUrl=/status` (status-page does not require login) and it seems to work since I will land on the statuspage. If I instead would set http://www.google.se as ReturnUrl it does not work. So my question is if it is possible to configure what is sent in to `ReturnUrl` for logout in `WebConfig` and does it always have to be relative to my applications url?

Kind Regards
Eric

Comment: Were you able to resolve this issue?

Comment: I ended up creating my own view for logout that just informed the user he was loged out and should close the browser.

Answer (score 1):

Only local URLs are allowed by default, to stop open redirect attacks.

If you want to allow a specific remote URL, you can implement the `ValidateAbsoluteReturnUrl` notification to return `true` for URLs in a whitelist. Don't "fix it" by simply returning `true` for anything - that will lead to an open redirect vulnerability.